# Dipolar moment between HI and HF

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, dipole

Which between $\ce{HI}$ and $\ce{HF}$ has a greater dipolar moment?
I think it is $\ce{HI}$ because the atomic radius of $\ce{I}$ is greater.

Comment: How much charge separation is between the atoms on each compound? What is the difference between electronegativities of H and I?  H and F?

Comment: F is more electronegative than I, how do I evalue if it compensates for the smaller distance?

Comment: One method is to look up the "rulr" for ionic character versus electronegativity difference, see the plot in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/why-are-bonds-ionic-when-the-electronegativity-difference-between-bonded-atoms-i.  Use the curve to figure out where HI might be.  Which is the bigger factor now, atomic size or charge separation?

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/dipole-moment-anomaly-in-fluorine-and-chlorine-compounds-what-factors-affect-th

Answer (score 2):

The dipole moment of $\ce{HF}$ is greater than $\ce{HI}$:

- $\ce{HF} = \pu{1.91 D}$
- $\ce{HI} = \pu{0.42 D}$

This is due to high electronegativity of fluorine. Hence from $\mu = \vec{q} \cdot \vec{d}$, the charge of fluorine is larger than iodine, but the bond length changes only a small amount.

Comment: How exactly is the charge related to the electronegativity?

Comment: Higher the charge per unit area on atomic surface more is the tendency of that atom to attract electrons. (Allred Rochow Electronegativity).